# Run service once a week, not also at boot

Tags: systemd

I have to run a `systemd` service only once a week and not also at system boot. These are the `.service` and `.timer` files:

`.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=kodi backup

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kodiback

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=kodi backup

[Timer]
OnCalendar=weekly
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

At the moment `systemd` runs this service also at system boot.

Comment: Not really sure, but could you try to remove the `Install` section in your `.service` file.

Comment: Is the service enabled? What is the output of `systemctl is-enabled kodi.service` (or whatever may be the name)?

Comment: `systemctl is-enabled kodibackup.service`

`enabled`
Yes, is enabled

Comment: I think that the problem was that I should have only enable the .timer. Right?

Comment: @Andrea993 Indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit runs on system boot because it is `enabled`. You want it to be started by the timer unit only.